# Magento2, How to create Duplicate add to cart process

Tags: magento2

How to create Duplicate add to cart process in magento2.

Answer (score 0):

I have create custom add to cart process for guets users for **Guest Wishlist Module**.

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

class GuestCart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $redirect;
    protected $_productloader;
    protected $quantityProcessor;
    protected $cart;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $itemsFacotry;
    private $optionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\LocaleQuantityProcessor $quantityProcessor,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item\OptionFactory $optionFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $itemsFacotry
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->quantityProcessor = $quantityProcessor;
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->itemsFacotry = $itemsFacotry;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        // get post data
        $itemId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('item'); // here set your product id
        $qty = $postQty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'); // here you set product qty 

        $store_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        // get product collection
        $product_data = $this->_productloader->create()->load($itemId);
        $prd_coll = $this->itemsFacotry->create();
        $prd_coll->setId($itemId);
        $prd_coll->setProductId($itemId);
        $prd_coll->setStoreId($store_id);

        if ($postQty !== null && $qty !== $postQty) {
            $qty = $postQty;
        }
        if (is_array($qty)) {
            if (isset($qty[$itemId])) {
                $qty = $qty[$itemId];
            } else {
                $qty = 1;
            }
        }
        $qty = $this->quantityProcessor->process($qty);
        if ($qty) {
            $prd_coll->setQty($qty);
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(' Please specify the quantity of ' . $product_data->getName());
            $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
            $resultRedirect->setPath($redirectUrl);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // Check configurable  product
        if ($product_data->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
            $this->messageManager->addNotice('You need to choose options for your item.');
            $resultRedirect->setPath($product_data->getProductUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        try {
            //add to cart product
            $prd_coll->addToCart($this->cart, true);
            $this->cart->save()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
            if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = __('You added ' . $product_data->getName() . ' to your shopping cart.');
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
            }
        } catch (ProductException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This product(s) is out of stock.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('We can\'t add the item to the cart right now.'));
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
        $resultRedirect->setPath($redirectUrl);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

> Here you have to pass two paramater in this controller. In above **item** for product ID and **qty** for product Quantity.

Create link like this

```
<?php echo $block->getUrl('quotation/index/guestcart').'item/54/qty/2'; ?>"
```

**Update :**

```
<?php
$prd_id = 45; //your product id
$qty = 2; // your product qty
$cart_url  =$block->getUrl('quotation/index/guestcart');
$cart_url .= "item/".$prd_id;
$cart_url .= "/qty/".$qty;
?>
<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($cart_url) ?>" ><button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary"> <span>Add to Quote</span> </button></a>
```

If cart item is not update add this to your phtml

```
<script>
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where I have to call this controller?

Comment: You can call controller from button, anchor tag href , form submit, etc there are many way to call controller.

Comment: Here I got this error  'Please specify the quantity of '

Comment: Hi @Raji please share your code. I will Help to solve your error.

Comment: <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('quotation/index/guestcart'); ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <div class="btn">
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
            <span>Add to Quote</span>
        </button>
    </div>   
 </form>

Comment: I add the value statically in controller

Comment: Update answer please check it

Comment: No sir, I got an error like this " Cannot specify product."

Comment: Can you please help me , how to add form for this??

Comment: Yes I will update Answer as soon as possible

Comment: Sorry some technical issue , I will post tomorrow morning.

Comment: answer is update please check it

Comment: Ok sir, I will check it. Thanks for your reference..

Comment: After try this code, I got an error like "Cannot specify product"..Can you please give me any other reference.

Comment: you should pass valid product id.